# Ant build.xml file > seems to be 'Skipping' all my TestNG Tests

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ant, webdriver

Ant build.xml file > seems to be 'Skipping' all my TestNG Tests

**Strungling to workout why the Ant build.xml file is skipping my tests?**

**Output 'Skipped Tests':**
[image]

**build.xml code:**

```
<project name="Sample Ant build" default="testng-execution" basedir=".">
    <!-- ========== Initialize Properties =================================== -->
    <!-- set global properties for build -->
    <property name="basedir" value="." />
    <property name="lib" value="${basedir}/lib" />
    <property name="src" value="${basedir}/src" />
    <property name="bin" value="${basedir}/bin" />
    <property name="report-dir" value="${basedir}/Test-Report" />
    <property name="testng-report-dir" value="${report-dir}/TestNGreport" />

    <!-- ====== Set the classpath ====  -->
    <path id="classpath">
        <pathelement location="${bin}" />
        <fileset dir="${lib}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- Delete directories  -->
    <target name="delete-dir">
        <delete dir="${bin}" />
        <delete dir="${report-dir}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Creating directories -->
    <target name="create" depends="delete-dir">
        <mkdir dir="${bin}" />
        <mkdir dir="${report-dir}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${bin} -->
    <target name="compile" depends="create">
        <javac srcdir="${src}" classpathref="classpath" includeAntRuntime="No" destdir="${bin}" />
        <echo> /* Compiled Directory Classes */ </echo>
    </target>

    <!-- Runs the file and generates Reportng report for TestNG-->
    <taskdef name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" classpathref="classpath" />

    <target name="testng-execution" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${testng-report-dir}" />
        <testng outputdir="${testng-report-dir}" classpathref="classpath" useDefaultListeners="true">
            <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="testng.xml" />
        </testng>
    </target>
</project>
```

project setup:
[image]

Comment: What are the contents of testng.xml?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="PH_Automation_Scripts_by_GBruno" verbose="2">
    <test name="PH Automation Tests: Pizza Combinations">
   <packages>
   <package name="PhFramework.pizzas.*" /> 
  </packages> 
 </test>
</suite>

Comment: Thank you. Please see if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179043/testng-skipping-tests-why

Comment: thanks @Rao I will have a read